# Getting error in PaypalHereEMVSampleApp of paypal here sdk

Tags: android, paypal

I am getting below error. I have attached steps to reproduce it.Before a week , it was working for me and now getting crash.

1. Run PaypalHereEMVSampleApp in Android device.
2. connect reader.
3. charge amount and press button "charge". get crash.

   ```
   06-25 10:38:40.447  20118-20118/au.com.optus.express.optuspaypalpoc    E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: au.com.optus.express.optuspaypalpoc, PID: 20118
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{au.com.optus.express.optuspaypalpoc/com.paypal.merchant.sdk.internal.emv.activities.EMVPaymentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.paypal.merchant.sdk.internal.util.f.b(MerchantUtil.java)
       at com.paypal.merchant.sdk.internal.emv.activities.EMVPaymentActivity.b(EMVPaymentActivity.java)
       at com.paypal.merchant.sdk.internal.emv.activities.EMVPaymentActivity.onCreate(EMVPaymentActivity.java)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5539)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   ```